# How to use image magick to stack (-append) tiffs numerically and not lexicographically?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I am attempting to convert a multipage pdf into a single (vertical) tiff file with the following codes.

1. magick -density 300 FILENAME.PDF -alpha remove -compress lzw page_%0d.tiff
2. magick page_*.tiff -append FINALFILENAME.tiff

Image magick stacks these vertically correctly. However, it stacks them lexicographically (0,1,10,11,12,13,...19,2,20,21,22,etc) and not numerically (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,etc.).

How can I fix this?

I have tried to ask ChatGPT to no avail.

Comment: Rename your files so that they have leading zeros. If you have a lot of files, you can find a number of renaming apps.  For example I use NameChanger from the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 2):

In your first command, you name the output files with "page_%0d.tiff", which results in file names with numbers like "... 8, 9, 10, 11...". You can have ImageMagick output those file names with leading zeros to get what you want.

```
magick -density 300 FILENAME.PDF -alpha remove -compress lzw page_%04d.tiff
```

In this command I used "page_%04d.tiff", which will output the file names using four digits with numbers like "... 0008, 0009, 0010, 0011...". Adjust that to accommodate the largest number of pages you expect.

EDITED TO ADD: If the only thing you're doing with these files is appending them into a single image, if there isn't a particular reason not to, you should probably just do it all in a single command...

```
magick -density 300 FILENAME.PDF -alpha remove -compress lzw -append FINALFILENAME.tiff
```

That should produce exactly the same result as your two commands.

Comment: The second suggestion (single command) worked perfect. Thank you so much! I am going to try the other commands for learning purposes as coding is not my strong suit. Thank you again for the suggestions and promptness.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in batch for multiple pdfs?

Comment: @dudleykid What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 11 within the command line

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are 3 methods listed here in total, so read on in case one of the later ones is better suited to your case. The methods are separated by a horizontal rule across the page.

---

### Method 1 - split sensibly in the first place

When you split the document into its separate pages, make sure the page numbers are zero-padded (I am using a total width of 4 digits here, which is good for up to 10,000 pages) by adding a width such `%04d`:

```
# Split document into separate pages, saving each as a TIFF
magick doc.pdf -compress lzw p-%04d.tif

# Combine TIFFs into a single, long TIFF
magick p-*.tif -append -compress lzw result.tif
```

---

Just so you can see how that first command numbers the pages - I'm using a 12-page document here, by the way:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff     76118 17 Feb 10:14 p-0000.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    301868 17 Feb 10:14 p-0001.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff     10604 17 Feb 10:14 p-0002.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    303310 17 Feb 10:14 p-0003.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    222920 17 Feb 10:14 p-0004.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    266712 17 Feb 10:14 p-0005.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    227114 17 Feb 10:14 p-0006.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    240232 17 Feb 10:14 p-0007.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    219172 17 Feb 10:14 p-0008.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    296376 17 Feb 10:14 p-0009.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    172198 17 Feb 10:14 p-0010.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    393538 17 Feb 10:14 p-0011.tif
```

Just for fun, note that you can start the pages at any number you desire using the [-scene](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#scene) parameter, so if I want them to start at page 34:

```
magick doc.pdf -scene 34 -compress lzw p-%04d.tif
```

**Output**

```
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff     76118 17 Feb 10:22 p-0034.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    301868 17 Feb 10:22 p-0035.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff     10604 17 Feb 10:22 p-0036.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    303310 17 Feb 10:22 p-0037.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    222920 17 Feb 10:22 p-0038.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    266712 17 Feb 10:22 p-0039.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    227114 17 Feb 10:22 p-0040.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    240232 17 Feb 10:22 p-0041.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    219172 17 Feb 10:22 p-0042.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    296376 17 Feb 10:22 p-0043.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    172198 17 Feb 10:22 p-0044.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    393538 17 Feb 10:22 p-0045.tif
```

---

### Method 2 - Use the shell's *"brace expansion"*

By the way, there is an alternative method which is to use the `bash` shell's *"brace expansion"* [function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) to enumerate the files in order for you. This might be useful if someone else split the pages and the page numbers are already fixed like this:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff     76118 17 Feb 10:29 p-0.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    301868 17 Feb 10:29 p-1.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff     10604 17 Feb 10:29 p-2.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    303310 17 Feb 10:29 p-3.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    222920 17 Feb 10:29 p-4.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    266712 17 Feb 10:29 p-5.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    227114 17 Feb 10:29 p-6.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    240232 17 Feb 10:29 p-7.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    219172 17 Feb 10:29 p-8.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    296376 17 Feb 10:29 p-9.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    172198 17 Feb 10:29 p-10.tif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    393538 17 Feb 10:29 p-11.tif
```

Here you can use:

```
magick p-{0..11}.tif -append result.tif
```

and your shell will list out the pages in order for **ImageMagick**. Likewise, you can just concatenate pages 1 and 5 with:

```
magick p-{1,5}.tif -append x.tif
```

Or, pages 1 and 5, plus pages 9 through 11:

```
magick p-{1,5}.tif p-{9..11}.tif -append x.tif
```

---

### Method 3 - Avoid intermediate output files

Another way of doing this, and avoiding intermediate output files, is to leverage the fact that **ImageMagick** is happy to process concatenated TIFFs. So use a first **ImageMagick** invocation to split the PDF into concatenated TIFFs and a second **ImageMagick** invocation to append them from the stream:

```
magick doc.pdf tiff:- | magick tiff:- -append result.tif
```

And, if you want to delete pages 2, 4 and 5, you can use **ImageMagick** [-delete](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#delete) option:

```
magick doc.pdf tiff:- | magick tiff:- -delete 2,4,5  -append result.tif
```

Note that there are other options to **ImageMagick** like `-delete` that will resequence, duplicate (`-duplicate`), reverse (`-reverse`), swap (`-swap`) or select specific pages.